# template inheritance of overrided bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-3.4

I am using symfony 3.4, but planning to update 4.0 in future.

So I reduce the bundle override step by step. ( it is prohibited in symfony 4)

For now I am planning to use template override in templtes directoly.

So I made the file here.

`/templates/bundles/ApplicationSonataMediaBundle/Form/media_widgets.html`

then cache clear

> php app/console  cache:clear

However it doesn't work.

My error messages are like this below.

```
Unable to find template "ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Form:media_widgets.html.twig"
 (looked into: /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views, 
 /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/app/Resources/views, 
 /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/templates, 
 /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).
```

Where should I check next??

Comment: why don't you put this file `/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/templates` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error message suggests, you have a call

```
$this->render('ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Form:media_widgets.html.twig');
```

somewhere (plus parameters). That syntax isn't used anymore, instead use:

```
$this->render('@ApplicationSonataMediaBundle/Form/media_widgets.html.twig');
```

as shown in [the Symfony templating docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle) (it appears this changed from symfony [3.1](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle) to [3.2](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle), if the docs can be trusted).

Comment: I have found the code in sonata_media.yml - `'ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Form:media_widgets.html.twig'`    I changed into         `'@ApplicationSonataMedia/Form/media_widgets.html.twig'` . than it worked. thanks!!